# Jquery tablesorter cant sort multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a problem with properly using `tablesorter` script. Here is How I am implementing my tables :

[Link to my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrand1r/wJPjZ/)

Unfortunately sorting works only on the first table. Funny thing is that if I create a copy of first table and give this table `id='myTable2'` sorting on the second table works as it should. I believe that there is something wrong with my table `syntax` but there is nothing highlighted by the `jsfiddle`. Even `FireBug` is not detecting any errors...

Can anyone point me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this in your 2nd table.

```
<thead></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UQxRL/)

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was so simple. Thank You @Anup !